# Передача массива на новый ViewController через Segue

Tags: массивы, swift

В сториборде создал два TVC, суть простая 
На первом два лейбла : Название услуги , Цена. 
На втором все идентично, хотел при нажатии определенной услуги получать эту же информацию на другом TVC.

```
**1ТVC**


 import UIKit
import CoreData

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBAction func unwindToThisViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){ // объявление сегвея для возврата на этот вью

    }
    var Serv:[services]=[
        services(name:"Переустановка Виндовс и чего то там там там тывдадывадвы вьыдвавыаь",price:"2000"),
        services(name:"Чистка ноутбука и тд ывлыдвлвалыальавы ыаьлыав",price: "1000"),
        services(name: "Замена термопасты жвыдьждыьвсждьывсжыжвсыдв", price: "500")
    ]

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) { // включаем свайп
        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 90
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    }
   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true) //что бы не было выделения на выбранном элементе
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return Serv.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.NameLabel.text = Serv[indexPath.row].name
        cell.PriceLabel.text = Serv[indexPath.row].price

        return cell
    }
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { 
        if segue.identifier == "bascetsegue"{
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            let dvc = segue.destination as! BascetTableViewController // Thread 1: signal SIGABRT 
            dvc.BascetServ = [self.Serv[indexPath.row]]

            }
        } 
}
```

Вот второй TVC куда я пытаюсь передать данный

```
import UIKit
```

class BascetTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
var BascetServ : [services] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 90   // метод для расширения ячейки
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return BascetServ.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! BascetTableViewCell
    cell.BascetName.text = self.BascetServ[indexPath.row].name
    cell.BascetPrice.text = self.BascetServ[indexPath.row].price
    return cell
}
```

В функции  ***override func prepare()*** выскакивает ошибка, когда пытаюсь совершить переход. 
Больше недели бьюсь и пытаюсь обойти эту ошибку, да опыта не хватает.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, был лишний Navigation View Conroller